# Xcode po is not printing output in debugging area

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

Xcode is not giving expected results when i try to print any object. I am using Xcode 12.4 .. In another mac its working fine.

> Ex: When i try to print the text inside the UITextField getting below
> error
>
> (lldb) po emailTextField.text
>
> expression produced error: error:
> /var/folders/5q/9vj8df5s0xs_2splf1fbwgzh0000gn/T/expr39-7ad9b9..swift:1:51:
> error: cannot specialize a non-generic definition
> Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<Swift.Optional<Swift.String>>(bitPattern:
> 0x10ba5a660)!.pointee)
> ^
>
> /var/folders/5q/9vj8df5s0xs_2splf1fbwgzh0000gn/T/expr39-7ad9b9..swift:1:64:
> note: while parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket
> Swift._DebuggerSupport.stringForPrintObject(Swift.UnsafePointer<Swift.Optional<Swift.String>>(bitPattern:
> 0x10ba5a660)!.pointee)
> ^
> (lldb)

I have tried all the options given in the App Dev answers and tried changing the xcode, still no luck

Spammers stay and Don't spam with your unrelated answers